# POST request doesn't is not sent, using python requests library

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am trying to send post request to Shopify's REST end point. But It didn't seem to work and when I inspected response object it looks like 'GET' request is sent:

[image: I need POST request to be sent but GET is executed]

I will appreciate your help.

EDIT: I just checked and it works with urllib3. So is it error in standard requests library?

Comment: Maybe the server is redirecting you after successful POST request. What do you see if you print `x.request.history`? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)